# Confused about object references in C#

Tags: c#, oop

Ok,

I have a matrix of enemies `Enemy enemyGrid[x, y]`

Then, in my code I get an instance of one of the enemies by calling `Enemy tmp = enemyGrid[a, b]`

But if I change a property in tmp it is not reflected the next time I load the object from the matrix into the the same object tmp.

Each time I am finished with tmp I need to make it `= null` to have the change reflected into the object in the gird?

Why is that? I thought that tmp would just hold a reference to the object and changes would be made directly in the main object.

Thanks.

CODE UPDATE:

Populating the grid:

```
Enemy [,] spriteGrid = new Enemy[countCols, countRows];
spriteGrid[x, y] = new Enemy();
```

Access an object and change properties:

```
Enemy tmp = spriteGrid[i, j];

tmp.canShoot = true;
tmp.Update(gameTime, game.Window.ClientBounds);
tmp.canShoot = false;
```

The last line (canShoot = false) does not reflect into the object stored in the grid.

Comment: "Each time I am finished with tmp I need to make it = null to have the change reflected into the object in the gird?". Are you asking or are you telling? Codes, please.

Comment: I would say there's nothing wrong with the code, assuming that the rest of the code does not do something weird since you didn't include the other code. You didn't include the code for `Enemy` definition, so I'm guessing that you actually created `struct Enemy`, in which that would be the cause of what you're facing because when you use a `struct`, it's not referencing the one in the grid, instead it actually made a copy of it. So, if you could update your question to include the code for `Enemy` too.

Comment: Agree. We must know if `Enemy` is a class or a struct. In either case, `tmp.canShoot = true;` and `tmp.canShoot = false;` operate on the same varible, so should work the same way. Are you inspecting the `spriteGrid` through the debugger? You might want to step acouple of extra lines ahead to see if `canShoot` of the `[i,j]`-th entry has changed or not.

Comment: Enemy is a class, i'll try the debugger now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
Enemy tmp = enemyGrid[a, b]
```

does *not* create a copy of the object in your matrix.  It creates an alias to the same object instance.  Changes to *tmp* do affect the instance in the grid that they alias.

Please post a short, complete code snippet that demonstrates the issue you are experiencing.

**UPDATE**

In your sample, you set

```
tmp.canShoot = true;
```

but then

```
tmpEnemy.canShoot = false;
```

Two different variables.

**Update 2**

@Amry's comment is also accurate... if *Enemy* is a *struct* instead of a *class*, you would see this very behavior.  That is because *struct* is a *value type*, meaning the assignment does create a copy rather than an alias.

Except for *very special* cases, you should *never* use a struct that is mutable (that is, a struct whose value can change after it is initially created).

Comment: Question updated. Also, I fixed the issue. It was something to do with scope. tmp is defined inside the loop, but if I define it outside the loop everything works ok. No longer need to say tmp = null. Weird.

Comment: In your sample at least, you set **tmp** to *true* but **tmpEnemy** to *false* (two different variables).

Comment: That was rushed and badly copied, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: Hi, no, it's not a struct but a class. I need to take the time to put together some sample code, need sleep first. :)